# Differentiating two tables x and y?

Tags: differentials

I have two tables x and y with x={673,674,675,...} and y={0,1,2,...} and delta=dx/dy. 
I would like to know how delta can be calculated knowing that delta is the derivative of x divided by the derivative of y.

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps something like this will be useful:

```
x = Range[10];
y = x^2;

Differences[y]/Differences[x]

(*{3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 13, 15, 17, 19}*)
```

or alternatively:

```
Divide @@@ Differences[{y, x} // Transpose]

(*{3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 13, 15, 17, 19}*)
```